# How to see C++ shared_ptr contents in Linux when debugging using Eclipse?

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, debugging

I am debugging a C++ program on Ubuntu using Eclipse Luna, and all the variables that are smart pointers (like shared_ptr) don't show there content, They just show the number of references and address, unlike in VS on Windows where i can see the contents of the managed object (just like with any regular raw pointer *ptr).

How can i do that in eclipse as well?

Answer (score 2):

I don' have the reputation to comment, but.

This problem is reported as a bug in bugs.eclipse.org 
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=462539

Considering luna is a relatively old version, I think upgrading is a valid option.